# Workaround to no `puppet module generate`?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

Is there a way to continue using `puppet module generate`? I'm using Puppet version 4.10 and earlier I was able to make one without issue, but today when I tried to make one I got the following error:

```
Error: This action has been replaced by Puppet Development Kit. For more information visit https://puppet.com/docs/pdk/latest/pdk.html.
Error: Try 'puppet help module generate' for usage
```

I understand that it is deprecated, but we're still using 4.10, so is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually running Puppet 4.10? Have you by any chance installed Puppet from a gem that is being found in your `$PATH` ahead of the system-wide Puppet binary? `which puppet` and `puppet --version` will show you where your shell thinks Puppet is and what version it is.

I can still run `puppet module generate` with Puppet 5.5.x, it displays the deprecation warning but it still works whereas with Puppet 6.x I get the same error as you which makes me think you're running 6.x somehow.

Comment: Ha you're totally right. I accidentally was using the Puppet ruby gem instead of the Puppet application installed on my machine. Fixed the Gemfile to set the Puppet version to 4.10.12 and haven't had an issue since. Thank you!